# how to return most frequent value for a certain column for each group in GROUP BY query?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have this example table:

```
  sort_order  product      color    productid   price
  ----------  -------      ------   ---------   -----
      1       bicycle       red      2573257     50
      2       bicycle       red      0983989     40
      3       bicycle       red      2093802     45
      4       bicycle       blue     9283409     55
      5       bicycle       blue     3982734     60
      1       teddy bear    brown    9847598     20
      2       teddy bear    black    3975897     25
      3       teddy bear    white    2983428     30
      4       teddy bear    brown    3984939     35
      5       teddy bear    brown    0923842     30
      1       tricycle      pink     2356235     25
      2       tricycle      blue     2394823     30
      3       tricycle      blue     9338832     35
      4       tricycle      pink     2383939     30
      5       tricycle      blue     3982982     35
```

I would like a query that returns the product, the average price and the most frequent color.

So my query in this example would be expected to return:

```
product      most_frequent_color     average_price
-------      -------------------     -------------
bicycle      red                     50
teddy bear   brown                   28
tricycle     blue                    31
```

The average part seems easy just grouping by product and using avg(price), but how can I solve the most frequent color part?

This is the query I can figure out myself so far, but i don't know how to get the most_frequent_color for each group:

```
SELECT product, avg(price) AS average_price from products
WHERE sort_order <= 5
GROUP BY product
```

In my real world table there are usually way more rows for each group than I'm interested in so I just get a limited amount of them using the sort_order field

For the rare groups that either have null in all the rows for "color" or that have more than one most frequent color I would like to return null in the most_frequent_color colum returned

Thank you for any help on this!

Comment: What's expected to happen if there are two (or more) most frequent colors for an item? You should perhaps add that to your sample data.

Comment: Looks like homework?  I would say that you need to think of it as a two-stage problem.

Comment: Expected result is unclear or wrong. Average price for red bicycle is 45 not 50. And for blue tricycle  average price is 38,33

Comment: @Alex.. the average is for the product, not by color.

Comment: @jarlh good point. I added a field "sort_order" to the example table. In my real world table I do have that and I am currently using sort_order < 12 in the where clause to limit to maximum 11 rows per group. However not sure how to handle the situation you mentioned... let me think...

Comment: @Alex. The average is calculated on all the rows returned for each group. The query is grouped by product

Comment: @jarlh If there would be more than one color with the same frequency I would prefer to have null returned. There are some cases(some products) for which I don't have the color column with value, but with null instead. In those cases the "most frequent color" returned would also need to be null

Comment: *The query is grouped by product*  So post your query if you have one

Comment: @Alex not sure I understand what you mean. What's wrong with the example table I created to ease illustrating my question?

Comment: There is no query in your post. But in comments you are specking about some query which is grouped. You mean the real query you have? or you group it just in your mind?

Comment: @Alex. I have edited my question reflecting the missing info you mentioned. Hopefully somebody will be able to suggest a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an additional query in the `SELECT` clause to effectively perform an aggregate query on the same data:

```
SELECT   t.product,
         Avg ( t.price ) AS average_price,
         (
                  SELECT   IF ( Count(*) = t4.count, NULL, t2.color ) 'color'
                  FROM     products t2
                  JOIN
                           (
                                    SELECT   t3.product,
                                             t3.color,
                                             count(*) 'count'
                                    FROM     products t3
                                    GROUP BY t3.product ,
                                             t3.color
                                    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
                           ) t4
                  ON       t2.product = t4.product
                           AND t2.color <> t4.color
                  WHERE    t2.product = t.product
                  GROUP BY t2.color
                  ORDER BY count(*) DESC limit 1
         ) AS most_frequent_color
FROM     products t
WHERE    t.sort_order <= 5
GROUP BY t.product
```

So we link the 2nd copy of `products` using the `product` column, select the count of each color (for that product) with most frequent at the top of the list, then take the 1st row only - hence the most frequent value of color for that product.

This is not the same as an inline view (which is placed in the `FROM` clause of the query).

**NOTE:**
This will work with MySQL, but it is not database agnostic.

**UPDATE:**
Now checks for more than 1 color with the same frequency and returns null.

Comment: thank you Raad for your help. I have tried your approach in my real world table which is a lot bigger than the example one and it just stays calculating until it reaches my socket timeout. Maybe your approach is very resource intensive? I'll try now the other approaches suggested. Thanks!

Comment: I just realized that I don't have the relevant fields indexed. I'll improve that right now and run the query again and let you know

Comment: @dodecafonico - yes, the right indexes will most certainly help!

Comment: after heavy indexing the query takes me altogether 140 seconds to complete. I guess it's acceptable since the other approaches suggested take longer.  The only problem is that it doesn't comply with one of the requirements because if more than one color is the most_frequent, the query returns the first one when it should return null

Comment: very strange but awesome. I had my query with your approach saved in my DBM(Navicat) queries and it was taking 140 secs. I copied and pasted it into a new query window and executed it and it only takes 0.86 seconds. Not sure if it is a bug of Navicat or what but my impression is that the saved query was mysteriously not using the indexes, but what do I know?

Comment: Fwiw, I suspect that this solution will be much slower than others proferred

Comment: @Strawberry - possibly, but the other answers use at least 2 queries at the lowest level, whereas mine uses 1. Whilst not necessarily significant (a single bad query can be much slower than several good ones combined) it does less aggregation with a single sub-query as opposed to 2 or 3. Also the OP did say `the other approaches suggested take longer` so maybe it's not so bad...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT m.product
     , AVG(m.price) avg_price
     , n.color most_frequent
  FROM my_table m
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.product
            , x.color
         FROM 
            ( SELECT product
                   , color
                   , COUNT(color) total
                FROM my_table
               GROUP
                  BY product
                   , color
            ) x
         JOIN
            ( SELECT product
                   , MAX(total) max_total
                FROM 
                   ( SELECT product
                          , color
                          , COUNT(color) total
                       FROM my_table
                      GROUP
                         BY product
                          , color
                   ) a
               GROUP
                  BY product
           ) y
         ON y.product = x.product
        AND y.max_total = x.total
     ) n
    ON n.product = m.product
 GROUP
    BY m.product;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach.

[Fiddle with sample data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cedc/1)

```
select r.product, q.color, r.avgprice
from
(
select product, avg(price) as avgprice
from t
group by product
) r
join
(
select p.product, p.color
from
(
select product, color, count(*) as cnt
from t 
group by product, color
 ) p
join
    (
    select product, max(cnt) as maxcnt 
    from (
    select product, color, count(*) as cnt
    from t
    group by product, color) x
    group by product) y
on y.product = p.product and y.maxcnt = p.cnt
 ) q
on r.product = q.product
```